# 'Comments are closed' on WordPress custom post type

Tags: wordpress

After looking through every similar question on here, none of it seems to do the trick for me.

I have a custom post type called 'leads' and I am declaring support for comments like so:

```
add_post_type_support( 'leads', 'thumbnail', 'comments' );
```

In my single-leads.php template I am calling the comments area like so:

```
<?php comments_template('/comments_file_name.php'); ?>
```

however all I get on the frontend is 'Comments are closed.'

Just testing out a standard post using the same php call, the comments area appears fine.

I went into Settings > Discussion and unchecked 'Allow people to post comments on new articles', Saved and checked and saved again to flush it through (as per one solution on here) but no change.

It is also worth noting when I go into one of my 'Leads' post types in the dashboard and going into Screen Options, I have no 'Discussion' checkbox so I cant even enable comments on a per post basis.

Can anyone advise what else I can try?

Comment: maybe try updating through SQL query.  Something like `UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = REPLACE (comment_status, 'closed', 'open') WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'lead';`.  Make sure you have a viable DB backup before you do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @justin R but updating via SQL query is a little beyond me. I shall try this as a last resort but will keep at it!

Comment: maybe related https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/why-are-the-comments-disabled-by-default-on-my-custom-post-types

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have resolved this.

Similar to Justin's answer but in a function. This works to enable comments by default on any post type.

```
function switch_on_comments_automatically(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET comment_status = 'open'")); 
}
switch_on_comments_automatically();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Enables the Excerpt meta box in Page edit screen.  
 */
function wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_pages() {
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_pages' );
?>
```

wordpress codex example on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) also mentions in note that **it should be called through 'init' hook** as in their example mentioned above. Add 'comments' to the above example, change for 'page' to 'leads' and check.

Comment: Thanks for this Rajesh. interestingly, adding this function adds the 'excerpt' check box to the screen options but still no comments.

Comment: As mentioned by me below that function it should have been modified like
    add_post_type_support('leads','excerpt','comments');

Answer (score 0):

```
function default_comments_off( $data, $postarr ) {
     if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' || $data['post_type'] == 'my-custom-post-type' ) {
          //New posts don't have an ID - So this checks if the post is new or already exists
          if( !($postarr['ID']) ){
               $data['comment_status'] = 0; //0 = false | 1 = true
          }
     }
     return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_off', '', 2);
```